# How to make the flash player background transparent in c#

Tags: c#

I have used ShockwaveFlash activeX control to display .swf file on the form. And to make the background transparant i set Wmode to transparent but the control is not showing transparant background. How can i set the ShockwaveFlash  background transparent

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The swf file's author needs to remove its own background. Not much what you can do after doing your part.

BTW, add a winform and a flash tag will help you. Your question has nothing to do with which language you use.